# How to derive (year-to-date) YTD values in SQL

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

So I have a SQL query that needs the AMOUNT value aggregated so that it sums/returns YTD (Year-to-Date) activity instead of periodic activity (*as shown below*), selecting from six tables:

1. JOURNAL
2. DATE
3. COMPANY,
4. DEPARTMENT
5. ACCOUNT_TYPE
6. ACCOUNT

| COMPANY | DEPARTMENT | DEPARTMENT_DESCRIPTION | ACCOUNT_TYPE | ACCOUNT_TYPE_DESCRIPTION | ACCOUNT | ACCOUNT_DESCRIPTION | PERIOD_MONTH | PERIOD_YEAR | AMOUNT | YTD_AMOUNT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CompanyA | DeptA | Department A | Type1 | Account Type 1 | Account1 | Account Description1 | Jan | 2023 | 1000.00 | 1000.00 |
| CompanyA | DeptA | Department A | Type1 | Account Type 1 | Account1 | Account Description1 | Feb | 2023 | 1500.00 | 2500.00 |
| CompanyA | DeptA | Department A | Type1 | Account Type 1 | Account1 | Account Description1 | Mar | 2023 | 2000.00 | 4500.00 |
| CompanyA | DeptA | Department A | Type1 | Account Type 1 | Account1 | Account Description1 | Apr | 2023 | 1200.00 | 5700.00 |
| CompanyA | DeptA | Department A | Type2 | Account Type 2 | Account2 | Account Description2 | Jan | 2023 | 800.00 | 800.00 |
| CompanyA | DeptA | Department A | Type2 | Account Type 2 | Account2 | Account Description2 | Feb | 2023 | 950.00 | 1750.00 |
| CompanyA | DeptA | Department A | Type2 | Account Type 2 | Account2 | Account Description2 | Mar | 2023 | 1100.00 | 2850.00 |
| CompanyA | DeptB | Department B | Type1 | Account Type 1 | Account1 | Account Description1 | Jan | 2023 | 1200.00 | 1200.00 |
| CompanyA | DeptB | Department B | Type1 | Account Type 1 | Account1 | Account Description1 | Feb | 2023 | 1800.00 | 3000.00 |

This is what I've tried thus far but I can't quite seem to get it to add up correctly.

```
SELECT
    COMPANY.code COMPANY,
    DEPARTMENT.code DEPARTMENT,
    DEPARTMENT.description DEPARTMENT_DESCRIPTION,
    ACCOUNT_TYPE.type_code ACCOUNT_TYPE,
    ACCOUNT_TYPE.type_description ACCOUNT_TYPE_DESCRIPTION,
    ACCOUNT.code ACCOUNT,
    ACCOUNT.description ACCOUNT_DESCRIPTION,
    UPPER(RIGHT(PERIOD.period, LEN(PERIOD.period) - 3)) PERIOD_MONTH,
    PERIOD.year PERIOD_YEAR,
    SUM(JOURNAL.amount) as AMOUNT,
    SUM(SUM(JOURNAL.amount)) OVER (PARTITION BY PERIOD.year, ACCOUNT.code ORDER BY DATE.date_key) YTD_AMOUNT
FROM
    JOURNAL
    LEFT JOIN DATE ON JOURNAL.date_key = DATE.date_key
    LEFT JOIN COMPANY ON JOURNAL.company_key = COMPANY.company_key
    LEFT JOIN DEPARTMENT ON JOURNAL=.department_key = DEPARTMENT.department_key
    LEFT JOIN ACCOUNT_TYPE ON JOURNAL.account_type_key = ACCOUNT_TYPE.account_type_key
    LEFT JOIN ACCOUNT ON JOURNAL.account_key = ACCOUNT.account_key
GROUP BY
    COMPANY.code,
    DEPARTMENT.code,
    DEPARTMENT.description,
    ACCOUNT_TYPE.type_code,
    ACCOUNT_TYPE.type_description,
    ACCOUNT.code,
    ACCOUNT.description,
    UPPER(RIGHT(PERIOD.period, LEN(PERIOD.period) - 3)),
    PERIOD.year
ORDER BY
    PERIOD.year,
    UPPER(RIGHT(PERIOD.period, LEN(PERIOD.period) - 3));
```

Here are some sample records from **JOURNAL:**

| JOURNAL_KEY | JOURNAL_NAME | DATE_KEY | AMOUNT | COMPANY_KEY | DEPARTMENT_KEY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SHA2(451) | Journal_1 | SHA2(18-OCT-23) | 789 | SHA2('pepsi') | SHA2('marketing') |
| SHA2(452) | Journal_1 | SHA2(sysdate) | 1000 | SHA2('pepsi') | SHA2('marketing') |

Here are some sample records from DATE:

| DATE_KEY | DATE_PERIOD_START | DATE_PERIOD_END | YEAR | QUARTER | MONTH |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SHA2(18-OCT-23) | 2023-10-01 | 2023-10-31 | 2023 | 4 | October |

How can I achieve the result set above? Much thanks in advance :)

Comment: Just to clarify, the results you are showing in the table are your desired result or "instead of periodic activity (as shown below)".  Your SQL query doesn't show an `AMOUNT` field, so it's a bit confusing.  My guess is you need to aggregate a sum based on what is in your group by (without any window function) to get the `AMOUNT` and then use a window function with a Window Frame to get a running total of those `AMOUNT` values.

Comment: Thanks @MikeWalton, realized I forgot to include that column (was doing some experimenting on fiddler), my bad. (It's been added now)

Comment: Could you show me an example of said window function please?

Comment: Take a look at this docs page for Window Frames:
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions-analytic#window-frame-syntax-and-usage

Comment: TY @MikeWalton, I didn't realize these were called WINDOW functions!

Comment: @JohnWick - I think the issue is in the order by clause within the window function. Can you share a couple of records from Journal and Date tables or the table schemas?

Comment: Absolutely @GoonerForLife, just updated my question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to order it by month(numerical value) to get the correct running total. If your date dimension table has all the dates in the Journal table, it is better to change to an inner join instead so you will not have nulls in the order by clause of the window function. I think this will do it. Please try it and let me know if you encounter any issue.

```
SELECT t.COMPANY,
       t.DEPARTMENT,
       t.DEPARTMENT_DESCRIPTION,
       t.ACCOUNT_TYPE,
       t.ACCOUNT_TYPE_DESCRIPTION,
       t.ACCOUNT,
       t.ACCOUNT_DESCRIPTION,
       t.PERIOD_MONTH,
       t.PERIOD_YEAR,
       SUM(t.AMOUNT) AS Amount, 
       t.YTD_AMOUNT       
FROM 
(SELECT
    COMPANY.code COMPANY,
    DEPARTMENT.code DEPARTMENT,
    DEPARTMENT.description DEPARTMENT_DESCRIPTION,
    ACCOUNT_TYPE.type_code ACCOUNT_TYPE,
    ACCOUNT_TYPE.type_description ACCOUNT_TYPE_DESCRIPTION,
    ACCOUNT.code ACCOUNT,
    ACCOUNT.description ACCOUNT_DESCRIPTION,
    UPPER(RIGHT(PERIOD.period, LEN(PERIOD.period) - 3)) PERIOD_MONTH,
    MONTH(DATE.DATE_PERIOD_START) AS _month,
    PERIOD.year PERIOD_YEAR,
    JOURNAL.YTD_AMOUNT,
    SUM(JOURNAL.YTD_AMOUNT) OVER (PARTITION BY PERIOD.year, ACCOUNT.code ORDER BY MONTH(DATE.DATE_PERIOD_START)) YTD_AMOUNT
FROM
    JOURNAL
    JOIN DATE ON JOURNAL.date_key = DATE.date_key
    LEFT JOIN COMPANY ON JOURNAL.company_key = COMPANY.company_key
    LEFT JOIN DEPARTMENT ON JOURNAL=.department_key = DEPARTMENT.department_key
    LEFT JOIN ACCOUNT_TYPE ON JOURNAL.account_type_key = ACCOUNT_TYPE.account_type_key
    LEFT JOIN ACCOUNT ON JOURNAL.account_key = ACCOUNT.account_key) t
GROUP BY t.COMPANY,
       t.DEPARTMENT,
       t.DEPARTMENT_DESCRIPTION,
       t.ACCOUNT_TYPE,
       t.ACCOUNT_TYPE_DESCRIPTION,
       t.ACCOUNT,
       t.ACCOUNT_DESCRIPTION,
       t.PERIOD_MONTH,
       t.PERIOD_YEAR,
       t.YTD_AMOUNT    
ORDER BY
    t.year,
    t._month;
```

Comment: Wouldn't this result in the same value being represented for every month of the year, rather than a running total?  This is why I thought a Window Frame was necessary.

Comment: Also, as you mentioned, I wanted to reiterate that JOIN is better performing than LEFT JOIN in Snowflake, so if you can change the others to be JOIN, as well, I'd recommend it.

Comment: You are right @MikeWalton. As the data was already aggregated inside the inner query, it would return the same data for each of the months. I modified the query to fix that. I also agree with you on changing the joins to inner join, but will leave that to John.